# Выборка из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблицы:

```
groups (id, name) с данными:

1 Яблоки
2 Груши
3 Дыни

products (id, name, group_id) с данными:

1 Семеринка 1
2 Мелба 1
3 Антоновка 1

products_copy (id, group_id, product_id) с данными
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 2 2
4 2 3
```

Т.е. яблоки Семеринка также показыватся в группах Груши и Дыни, Мелба и Антоновка в группе Груши.

Вопрос, как сделать выборку групп с результатом 1,2,3. Т.е. найти основную группу и дубликаты из products_copy. Можно и с использованием php.

Comment: не совсем понял что вы хотите получить в результате запроса?? может как то по другому объясните? или еще лучше напишите каким должен быть результат в виде таблицы?

Comment: Один товар может лежать в разных группах (products и products_copy), мне нужно найти все эти группы (в примере выше это id групп 1,2,3). Так понятнее?

Comment: И так нет.

Comment: Нужно выбрать все id групп, для товара, который находится в таблице products_copy и products, так?

Comment: @Зоркий, а зачем вообще указывать id группы в таблице products? Если я правильно понял как всё устроено, от него можно избавиться, и сделать таблицу product_groups (вместо products_copy), в которой ввести признак "основная группа". Заодно решится и потенциальная проблема, когда у одного продукта могут быть несколько основных групп.

Comment: согласен, пример просто не очень удачный, чтобы понять суть вопроса ) просто пример должен показывать что он выбирает, а в твоем примере выборка дает просто все группы.

Comment: @klopp реализация изначально кривая - спору нет, как так получилось? Очень просто, сначала у товара была 1 группа, а потом появилась необходимость показывать товар в дополнительных группах, вот и получился такой костыль, исправлять чужие ошибки совершенно не хочется, хочется быстро сделать ещё 1 костыль и забыть :)

Comment: Один товар может быть в нескольких группах, реализовано это как описано выше. Моя задача найти эти дублирующие группы и заменить их на 1 - основную, делается это для сео, чтобы убрать 100% дубли страниц на разных адресах.
З.Ы. Вообще там внутри такой ахтунг творится, что страшно что либо трогать школоло стайл решает :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял тайный замысел:

```
select name, group_concat(cast(pc.group_id as char))
    from products_copy pc join products p on pc.product_id=p.id
    group by name;
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понял задачу, на столько и решил:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t2.name, t1.name  
FROM `groups` as t1, `products` as t2, `products_copy` as t3 
WHERE (t1.id = t2.group_id OR t1.id = t3.group_id) AND t2.id = t3.product_id
```

Идея в следующем: объединяем таблицы, `products` и `products_copy` из них выбираем id группы, которая равна `products`.`group_id` или `products_copy`.`group_id`

По данным таблицам у меня получился результат:

```
id | name      | name 
1  | Семеринка | Яблоко
2  | Семеринка | Груша
3  | Семеринка | Дыня
1  | Мелба     | Яблоко
2  | Мелба     | Груша
1  | Антоновка | Яблоко
2  | Антоновка | Груша
```

чтобы получить нужный для вас 1,2,3 необходимо поменять у селекта выводимые данные

Comment: Хмм, выбралось абсолютно всё, как теперь определить какая группа к какому дублю относится.

З.Ы. Можно и php использовать для решения.

Comment: хм, собственно, вот таблицы: 

> FROM `groups` as t1, `products` as t2, `products_copy` as t3 . 

из нужной таблицы просто вытаскиваешь данные, или фильтруешь по ним.